# RxJava - counter with x of y

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

How can I do this? I came up with following, it allows me to calculate the x in x of y, but how can I improve that to calculate the y as well?

```
Observable<LoadedPhoneContact> phoneContacts = getPhoneContacts()
        .flatMapObservable(contacts -> Observable.fromIterable(contacts));

Observable<Integer> phoneContactsCounter = phoneContacts
        .cache()
        .map(contact -> 1)
        .reduce((c1, c2) -> c2 + c2)
        .toObservable();

mSimils = phoneContacts
        .zipWith(phoneContactsCounter, (contact, index) -> new Pair<>(contact, index))
        .doOnNext(data ->  {
            L.d("x / y = %d / %d", data.second, ?);
        })
        .map(data -> SimilUtil.calcSimils(data))
        ;
```

Any ideas or better/alternative solutions?

I want to be able to see the progress in a format like "x of y items processed"...

I could zip with a third observable that just emits the count, but is this the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
Observable<?> result = Observable.defer(() -> {
    int[] counter = { 1 };
    return getPhoneContacts()
        .toObservable()
        .flatMapIterable(list -> list, (list, element) -> {
             L.d("x / y = %d / %d", counter[0]++, list.size());
             return SimilUtil.calcSimils(element);
        });
});
```

Comment: That works. Actually I always thought having some variable outside of the stream flow is no good design, that's why I tried to find another way

Comment: That's why I use defer() which you can use to add per-subscriber state, such as index much cheaper than zipping.

Comment: I realised that that's the reason for defer, just did not think about it myself before. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I definitely recommend not to have side effects inside Rx callbacks, as this can easily cause thread synchronization issues (which you're avoiding by using Rx in the first place).

Instead, you can use [rxjava-extras](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava2-extras) which has `.mapWithIndex(...)` -operator.